# Use OFFSET Function on merge cells - EXCEL

Tags: excel, offset

i trying to get the value of a cell using `OFFSET` function but i getting `0` due to merge area.

Scenario:

- A1:A5 is merge
- C1:C5 use the has formula: `=OFFSET(C1,0,-2)`

For `C1` i m getting the correct result but for the other cells i m getting 0.

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use INDEX not OFFSET:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",$A$1:A1))
```

[image]

---

Or if one has it XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP("*",$A$1:A1,$A$1:A1,"",2,-1)
```

[image]

---

If you really want the Volatile OFFSET:

```
=OFFSET(C1,MATCH("zzz",OFFSET(C$1:C1,0,-2))-ROW(),-2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I ll test it tomorrow and provide a feedback! Thanks for your time. The negative vote is not mine

Comment: why we use `zzz` in this formula `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",$A$1:A1))`

Comment: It returns the last cell in the range that has text in it, by looking for a text string that would always come at the end if sorted.  If the column is numbers then we would use `1E+99` for the same reason.  without the third criterion in the MATCH it would return the last cell in the range that has text.